# How to solve "undefined method belogns_to" for db association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I set an association in my db and i got some trouble...

one category will own many beacons

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :beacons
end
```

one beacon just belongs to one category, and beacons table has a column which named **cid** to associate with category's **id**

```
class Beacon < ActiveRecord::Base
    belogns_to :category, foreign_key: "cid"
end
```

but when i try to post some JSON request, server tells me:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `belogns_to' for #<Class:0x007fb15cf053b0>):
  app/models/beacon.rb:2:in `<class:Beacon>'
  app/models/beacon.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
```

did i missed somthing to add? 
or i have to add some gem to get belogns_to and has_many method? 
or something wrong in my table setting?
i use rails 4.2.2

Thanks!

Comment: I believe you mistyped "belongs_to" :)

Comment: thanks! it's really a stupid mistake!

Comment: should this be deleted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

typo, it should be spelled "belongs_to" :)